# Running NM cable in basement

Tags: wiring, drywall, basement

I am finishing my basement. Is it alright to run cables across 2x4’s as shown in the picture. The top plate of the wall will run parallel to the joist and perpendicular to the  cleats. The top plate will be nailed to the cleats. The cleats are less than 16” apart. Drywall will be installed on ceilings and walls.

[image]